# print with carriage return not working, printing new lines

Tags: python, cmd, printing

I have a bit of python code that is used to "clean up" a keylogger log, (educational purposes) and this is how it goes. I wanted to make it look cool by displaying the changes every time it gets changed and wanted to do it like this;

Helloo[bkspace] => then gets replaced by Hello.

The code for this is working but the print results in new lines.

```
def readfile_keylog(filein, fileout):
    fi = open(filein, "r")
    fo = open(fileout, "a")

    for line in fi:
        while "[bkspace]" in line:
            index = line.index("[bkspace]")
            line = line.replace("[bkspace]", "", 1)
            line = line[:index - 1] + line[index:]
            print("\r", str(line), end="", flush=True)

        fo.write(line)


readfile_keylog("login.txt", "out.txt")
```

I even tried using sys.stdout.write and flushing and it didnt work. when I tried simple code like this it works fine

```
for i in range(10):
  print("\r", i, end="", flush=True)
  time.sleep(0.1)
```

this is how the output looks, obviously not my intention.

```
 i feel like if you have it all the time the same people would be jki[bkspace][bkspace][bkspace]kinda forced to rush the [bkspace] ci[bkspace][bkspace]10[bkspace][bkspace]civilwear[bkspace][bkspace][bkspace]ars early 
 i feel like if you have it all the time the same people would be jk[bkspace][bkspace]kinda forced to rush the [bkspace] ci[bkspace][bkspace]10[bkspace][bkspace]civilwear[bkspace][bkspace][bkspace]ars early 
 i feel like if you have it all the time the same people would be j[bkspace]kinda forced to rush the [bkspace] ci[bkspace][bkspace]10[bkspace][bkspace]civilwear[bkspace][bkspace][bkspace]ars early 
 i feel like if you have it all the time the same people would be kinda forced to rush the [bkspace] ci[bkspace][bkspace]10[bkspace][bkspace]civilwear[bkspace][bkspace][bkspace]ars early 
 i feel like if you have it all the time the same people would be kinda forced to rush the ci[bkspace][bkspace]10[bkspace][bkspace]civilwear[bkspace][bkspace][bkspace]ars early 
 i feel like if you have it all the time the same people would be kinda forced to rush the c[bkspace]10[bkspace][bkspace]civilwear[bkspace][bkspace][bkspace]ars early 
 i feel like if you have it all the time the same people would be kinda forced to rush the 10[bkspace][bkspace]civilwear[bkspace][bkspace][bkspace]ars early 
 i feel like if you have it all the time the same people would be kinda forced to rush the 1[bkspace]civilwear[bkspace][bkspace][bkspace]ars early 
 i feel like if you have it all the time the same people would be kinda forced to rush the civilwear[bkspace][bkspace][bkspace]ars early 
 i feel like if you have it all the time the same people would be kinda forced to rush the civilwea[bkspace][bkspace]ars early 
 i feel like if you have it all the time the same people would be kinda forced to rush the civilwe[bkspace]ars early 
 i feel like if you have it all the time the same people would be kinda forced to rush the civilwars early
```

The results look like this in terminal and pycharm.

Comment: dont you dare tell me this is a duplicate LOL

Comment: tried on cmd, windows terminal, and pycharm same result. bump

Comment: This depends entirely on how your terminal (or editor, or pager, etc) *displays* `\r`, and is not something Python can control.

Comment: incorrect @chepner look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Its taking lines from the file. the lines contain a new line at the end. just needed to remove that with a simple if, anyways, i opted for a different way by clearing the console.

heres how it looks now, quite satisfying
https://streamable.com/rtkg2p

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try clearing console after each input before printing again?

```py
import os
print("hi")
os.system("cls")
print("bye")
```

Comment: this works too. anyways lines from files contain \n, good thing to know for next time